# Pandas открыть файл excel

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, как открыть файл excel, где в первом столбике разноуровневые данные, мне необходимо открыть его в pandas с такими же разными уровнями. Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Были следующие попытки:

```
pd.read_excel('May.xlsx', sheet_name='May', header=list(range(3)))
```

```
pd.read_excel('May.xlsx', sheet_name='May', header=list(range(3)), index_col=0)
```

Уровни отличаются между собой пробелами, но при прочтении файла пробелы убираются

Comment: Какие попытки у вас были решить задачу самостоятельно? Добавьте их, пожалуйста, в вопрос.

Comment: А чем эти разные уровни между собой отличаются? только количеством пробелов в начале строки? и исходные данные надо прикладывать к вопросу, равно как и попытку своего решения.

Comment: а какой практический смысл в этих уровнях, если они по сути не являются мультииндексом?

Comment: Уровни без пробелов, то есть первые, являются основными и мне их надо суммировать по составляющим (которые с пробелами) и потом удалить

Comment: У меня считывается тестовый файл с пробелами.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Скорее в всего, проблема в аргументах функции, их правильной настройке, может, что-то пропустили

Comment: Да, так и есть, получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На тестовом файле у меня получилось следующее:

```
test.xlsx
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
main.py
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', skiprows=[1, 2, 3])
# Берем из номенклатуры первые два символа и если это два пробела заменяем их на nan.
df['основной код'] = df['номенклатура'].str[0:2].replace('  ', np.nan)
# Заполняем не nan значения из столбца код.
df['основной код'].mask(df['основной код'].notna(), df['код'], inplace=True)
# Заполняем nan значения предыдущим действительным значением.
df['основной код'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
print(df)

-----------------------------

        номенклатура     код  количество  основной код
0                 Д4  123456           2        123456
1       Полуфабрикат  123460           2        123456
2          Заготовка  123464           2        123456
3              Днище  123468           2        123468
4              Днище  123472           4        123472
5       Полуфабрикат  123476           4        123472
6          Заготовка  123480           4        123472
7              Днище  123484           2        123484
8              Днище  123488           2        123484
9       Полуфабрикат  123492           2        123484
10         Заготовка  123496           2        123484
11             Днище  123500           4        123500
12      Полуфабрикат  123504           4        123500
13         Заготовка  123508           4        123500
14             Днище  123512           3        123512
15      Полуфабрикат  123516           3        123512
16         Заготовка  123520           3        123512
```

Каждая группа получила свой идентификатор. Теперь вы можете или создать мультииндекс, или группировать по нему.